# Do I need to close a hibernate stateless session if I provide a spring managed DB connection?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

If I have a Spring Transaction managed DataSource, and use it to provide the connection to a Hibernate stateless session, do I need to close the stateless session? And if so, would it be a noop with regards to closing the DB connection and committing the DB transaction?

This is what I have now:

```
import java.sql.Connection;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.StatelessSession;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils;

...

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

public MyObj getCurrentByName(String name)
{
   StatelessSession session = null;

   try
   {
      Connection conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
      session = sessionFactory.withStatelessOptions()
            .connection(conn)
            .openStatelessSession();

      return (MyObj) session.createCriteria(MyObj.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("isCurrent", true))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("name", name))
            .setComment("MyObj by name")
            .uniqueResult();
   }
   finally
   {
      if (session != null)
      {
         session.close();
      }
   }
}
```

So again, is the session.close() going to just clean up the session object? i.e. not commit the txn nor close the DB connection?